# Bootstrap issues with margin in container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, containers

I have issues with **container**. I want to change **margin** of container but I dont know how to do that.
I have tried to change css file, margin-left and margin-right but it doesnt work good. Its not centered its more to the right or left so need to fix that problem. So please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

Margin is how Bootstrap's `.container` class center-positions itself horizontally. Try using padding instead.